# Flash AS3 - Combine Multiple Variable Names Together to Target New Variable

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, object

I'm still learning flash and actionscript 3 and i am having trouble with variable and object names. I need to be able to combine variable names together (in the same way as php can combine by doing var1.var2).

My swf contains 4 loaders (**image1_loader, image2_loader etc..**) which are a child of (**image1_content, image2_content etc...**..)
I then have 4 buttons which load an image into the loader and while doing so they define the currently active loader.
Finally i have 4 control buttons - scale up/down and rotate clockwise/anticlockwise which should only control the currently active loader (as set by the buttons above)

So my buttons as well as loading the image have the event listener:

```
image1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setCurrentSelection);
image2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setCurrentSelection);
```

(and so on..)

```
function setCurrentSelection(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (e.currentTarget===image1_btn){activeLoader='image1';}
    if (e.currentTarget===image2_btn){activeLoader='image2';}
    if (e.currentTarget===image3_btn){activeLoader='image3';}
    if (e.currentTarget===image4_btn){activeLoader='image4';}
}
```

So after setting my activeLoader as the string 'imageX' i have a control functions as in this rotate one:

```
rotateClock_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rotateClockwise);
rotateAnti_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rotateAntiClockwise);

function rotateClockwise(event:Event):void {
    rotateAroundCenter(imageX_content, 10, ptR);
}

function rotateAntiClockwise(event:Event):void {
    rotateAroundCenter(imageX_content, -10, ptR);
}
```

**So within the rotateClockwise and rotateAntiClockwise functions i need to be able to recognise which is the currently active loader and have that number instead of the X - so if it is image1_loader - it needs to be image1_content, if 4 - image4_content...
I had tried to do it as this but it doesn't like it being a string:**

```
rotateAroundCenter((activeLoader+'_content'), 10, ptR);
```

Please could anyone help me understand how to solve (sorry if i havent explained it clearly!) and please go easy on me - i'm learning as i go myself

Lauren :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have one to one map of content DisplayObjects to Loaders you can save content in a variable.

```
function setCurrentSelection(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (e.currentTarget===image1_btn){activeContent=image1_content;}
    if (e.currentTarget===image2_btn){activeContent=image2_content;}
    if (e.currentTarget===image3_btn){activeContent=image3_content;}
    if (e.currentTarget===image4_btn){activeContent=image4_content;}
}

function rotateClockwise(event:Event):void {
    rotateAroundCenter(image4_content, 10, ptR);
}
```

If for some reason you need to store string name of loader you can do it like this

```
function rotateClockwise(event:Event):void {
    rotateAroundCenter(getChildByName(activeLoader+"_content"), 10, ptR);
}
```

If image1_loader and others are on Stage.

Even better, you can use bubbling and do this (assuming that you have your images and contents DisplayObjects in the same scope).

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setCurrentSelection);

function setCurrentSelection(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var name:String = e.target.name;
    var index:int = name.indexOf("_btn");
    if (index == -1) return;
    activeLoader = name.substr(0, index);    
}

function rotateClockwise(event:Event):void {
    rotateAroundCenter(getChildByName(activeLoader+"_content"), 10, ptR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were trying to do...

```
rotateAroundCenter(getChildByName([activeLoader+"_content"]), 10, ptR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the elements relating to one item in a custom object, and use an Array of these objects to store them.  That way, you a) avoid having to tediously compare name strings, and b) create a solution that would possibly accept a gzillion loaders, if needed ;)

```
var numLoaders : int = 4;
var items : Array = [];
var activeItem : Object = null;

init();

function init() : void {
    var i: int = -1;
    while (++i < numLoaders) {
        var item : Object = { 
           btn: getChildByName ("image"+i+"_btn"), 
           image: getChildByName ("image"+i+"_content") 
        };
        item.btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, setSelection);
        items.push ( item ); 
    } 
}

function setSelection (e:Event) : void {
    var i:int = -1;
    while (++i < items.length) {
        if (e.currentTarget == items[i].btn) activeItem = item; // compare by reference, not by name!
        break;
    }
}

function rotateClockwise(event:Event):void {
    if (activeItem) rotateAroundCenter(activeItem, 10, ptR);
}
```

I went with `getChildByName()` because I assume you have these elements on the stage already -  you could also assign the items within a creation loop.

Also, I used 0-based index numbers by convention.  If your items start at "image1", use

```
var i : int = 0;
while (++i <= numLoaders)
```

in the first loop.